# SimpleDateFormat format разные результаты

Tags: java, дата, simpledateformat

Разное значение при форматировании даты в строку на разных машинах.

```
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+03:00"));
sdf.format(date.getTime());
```

yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX должен вернуть дату в виде String, где XXX будет +TimeZone, то есть +03:00

На одной машине получается правильный результат `2018-06-08T13:47:16+03:00`, а на другой - неправильный `2018-06-08T13:47:16Z`.

Кто может подсказать в чем причина?

```
java version "1.8.0_162"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Нету входящих данных. Поправьте код так, что б можно было повторить. Не понятно что содержит hr? И futureDate тоже.

Comment: sdf.format возвращает разные результаты на разных ОС. Я снова обновил вопрос.

Comment: Так понятно. +TimeZone не отображает.

Comment: А "Z" может значить, что зону не выставили, т.е. она +0?

Comment: Я тоже подумал, поэтому задаю время setTimeZone

Comment: посмотрите, что возвращает `TimeZone.getTimeZone`, согласно документации оно возвращает GMT, если не понимает идентификатор

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давным-давно я как-то касался подобного вопроса, там проблема была в том, что `timezone` в Windows была какая то кривая.

Исправлялось просто:

```
TimeZone tz=TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+03"); //вместо GMT+03:00
```

Да и проверьте списки `TimeZone.getAvailableIds(3*60*60*1000)` на разных машинах они будут другие (берется из ОС)

Comment: как всегда помогла магия. и после того, как убрал :00 - все заработало.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку Вы используете java 8, я бы посоветовал попробовать использовать API, который предоставляет уже сама JDK в пакете java.time. Как мне кажется это более нативный подход.
Попробуйте использовать вот этот код:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter= DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
ZonedDateTime.now().format(formatter);
```

Надеюсь это решит Вашу проблему, пусть и не даст ответ на вопрос, почему не работает Ваш вариант.

Comment: тоже хороший ответ. плюс